# Program to sort user entered array from lowest to highest. C programming

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, swap

I have written a code that takes in an input of n numbers stored into an array. Then, the code will order those n numbers from lowest to highest. I am having trouble with my swap function to order the numbers. Two of my other functions will call the swap function, so I will include that as well to show more of what I am doing.

```
void swap(int array[], int index1, int index2)   {
   *array = index1;
   index1 = index2;
   index2 = *array;
}

 void quicksort(int array[], int low, int high)   {
   if (low<high)   
   {
      int pivot = partition(array, low, high);
      quicksort(array, low, pivot - 1);
      quicksort(array, pivot + 1, high);
   }
 }

int partition(int array[], int low, int high)  {
   int pivot = array[high];
   int i = low;
   int j;
   for(j=low; j<high-1; j++)   
   {
      if(array[j] == pivot)   
      {
         swap(array,i,j);
         i = i+1;    
      }    
   }
   swap(array, i, high);
   return i;
}
```

****EDIT****

I have written a code that takes in an input of n numbers stored into an array. Then, the code will order those n numbers from lowest to highest. I am having trouble with my swap function to order the numbers. Two of my other functions will call the swap function, so I will include that as well to show more of what I am doing.

```
void swap(int array[], int index1, int index2)   {
   *array = index1;
   index1 = index2;
   index2 = *array;
}

 void quicksort(int array[], int low, int high)   {
   if (low<high)   
   {
      int pivot = partition(array, low, high);
      quicksort(array, low, pivot - 1);
      quicksort(array, pivot + 1, high);
   }
 }

int partition(int array[], int low, int high)  {
   int pivot = array[high];
   int i = low;
   int j;
   for(j=low; j<high-1; j++)   
   {
      if(array[j] <= pivot)   
      {
         swap(array,i,j);
         i = i+1;    
      }    
   }
   swap(array, i, high);
   return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that swap function is wrong . YOu mean

```
void swap(int array[], int index1, int index2)   {
  int temp  = array[index1];
  array[index1] = array[index2];
  array[index2] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works better than what I had. Still an error somewhere in my code, but I am closer to the finish now.

Comment: step through with a debugger

Answer (score 0):

Finished and correct functions

```
void swap(int array[], int index1, int index2)   {
   int temp = array[index1];
   array[index1] = array[index2];
   array[index2] = temp;
}

 void quicksort(int array[], int low, int high)   {
   if (low<high)   
   {
      int pivot = partition(array, low, high);
      quicksort(array, low, pivot - 1);
      quicksort(array, pivot + 1, high);
   }
 }

int partition(int array[], int low, int high)  {
   int pivot = array[high];
   int i = low;
   int j;
   for(j=low; j<=high-1; j++)   
   {
      if(array[j] <= pivot)   
      {
         swap(array,i,j);
         i = i+1;    
      }    
   }
   swap(array, i, high);
   return i;
}
```